# Питання щодо відмінювання іменників

Tags: іменники, відмінювання

Мене ще зі школи цікавило питання щодо закінчення іменників у місцевому відмінку з прийменником "по". Я вже ставив це питання Інституту української мови, вони відповіли, але їхня відповідь здалася мені не повною.

Справа в тім, що в російській мові прийменник "по" вживається з давальним відмінком. А в українській за всіма канонами - з місцевим. Але ж можливо через калькування з російської, а може через інші причини майже ніхто не пише у ЗМІ "дивитись по телевізорі", "вдарити по м'ячі".

Практично всі друковані джерела вказують, що правильно "дивитись по телевізору" і "вдарити по м'ячу", що є, як на мене, нелогічним і очевидною калькою з російської. Можна сказати, що допускається як "-і" так і "-у", але ж ні - "журнал лежить на телевізорі", аж ніяк не "на телевізору", "рука на м'ячі", аж ніяк не "на м'ячу". У множині, до речі, значно частіше пишуть правильно "дивився по телевізорах", "бив по м'ячах". А от з одниною, як то кажуть, не все так однозначно.

Можна сказати, що це якісь сталі вирази, але ж більше скидається на те, що чомусь в підсвідомості десь закріплено, що "по" - це давальний відмінок, і все це виливається в однину, а от у множині закріплено нормально.

Будь ласка поясніть - все ж чи припустимо проводити аналогії у цій справі з російським відмінюванням, чи все ж таки можна і "по телевізорі" і "по телевізору"?

Comment: Вітаю на сайті. Перепрошую, але у нас не прийнято писати вітання, подяки чи інформацію про себе прямо в тексті запитань/відповідей. Вдячність краще висловлювати оцінками і/або відповідаючи на чужі записання. Про себе можна написати [в профілі](/users/edit/4455). (Утім, щодо коментарів наші настанови не такі суворі :).)

Comment: Вживання прийменника "по" не властиве для української мови. Кажуть "дивитися у телевізорі", "вдарити м'яча".

Answer (score 1):

#### Об'єктивно

«Український правопис» 2019 каже так:

> Примітка 1. Із прийменниками по деякі іменники набувають варіантних закінчень - у (-ю) та -і (-ї): по ду́бу — по ду́бі, по Дніпру́ — по Дніпрі́, по мі́сту — по мі́сті, по обли́ччю — по обли́ччі, по о́зеру — по о́зері, по по́лю — по по́лі, по селу́ — по селі́, по навча́нню — по навча́нні; на позначення часу вживається переважно закінчення -і (-ї): по закі́нченні, по обі́ді; зрідка — -у(-ю): по ве́чорі і по ве́чору, по дося́гненні і по дося́гненню, по заве́ршенні і
> по заве́ршенню, по закі́нченні і по закі́нченню, по зді́йсненні і по зді́йсненню.

І ще про назви істот (не осіб):

> Примітка 2. Із прийменником по іменники набувають варіантних закінчень -ові, -еві (-єві) та -у (-ю): по ле́вові і по ле́ву, по во́вкові і по во́вку; по бугає́ві і по бугаю́, по за́йцеві і по за́йцю; по вуже́ві і по вужу́.

Тобто (з 1-ї примітки виходить, що) обидва варіанти дозволені: *по телевізорі* і *по телевізору*. На практиці, звісно, *по телевізору* кажуть частіше (3414 траплять у «ГРАК-14» проти 14 траплянь там же).

#### Суб'єктивно

Я не лінгвіст, але мій суб'єктивний погляд полягає в тому, що система відмінків не є бездоганною ані в українській, ані в російській.

- Це, принаймні мені, найбільше видно на прикладі російської мови:

  > • Місцевий відмінок не повністю збігається з прийменниковим (*на снегу* — *о снеге*, *на мосту* — *о мосте*).
  > • Все ще наявні залишки кличного відмінка (*Боже*, *отче*).
  > • Родовий відмінок у кількісно-видільному значенні (*налей мне молока*).
  > • Другий знахідний відмінок (*беру в помощники*).
  > • Другий родовий, або партитив (*налить чаю*).
- Але таке є і в українській мові:

  - *написати листа* — семантично тут має бути знахідний відмінок, але типова форма знахідного відмінка від слова *лист* — *лист*; зазвичай сходяться на тому, що це особлива форма знахідного відмінка (хоча дехто вважає це родовим);
  - *вийти в люди* — семантично тут має бути знахідний відмінок, але типова форма знахідного відмінка від слова *люди* — *людей*; зазвичай сходяться на тому, що це особлива форма знахідного відмінка;
  - *по всіх куточках* — тут після *по* щось схоже на місцевий; *по телевізору* — тут після *по* щось схоже на давальний.

Фактично система відмінків не покриває всі можливі випадки. На мій погляд: теоретично відмінків мало б бути більше; але, імовірно, хтось колись вирішив не переускладнювати модель (а обійтися меншим числом, вважаючи все, що «не влізло», — винятками).

Конкретно щодо *по*, то можна було: (а) вважати, що після цього прийменника йде якийсь окремий відмінок (не давальний і не місцевий; але форми цього відмінка можуть збігаються з давальним чи з місцевим — у залежності від слова); (б) вважати, що після цього прийменника завжди йже давальний відмінок (а те, що часто форма слова нагадує місцевий, то це, мовляв, не справжній місцевий, а просто особлива форма, виняток); (в) вважати, що після цього прийменника завжди йже місцевий відмінок (а те, що часто форма слова нагадує давальний, то це, мовляв, не справжній давальний, а просто особлива форма місцевого, виняток). От, імовірно, хтось колись вирішив класифікувати способом «в». Можливо, через семантику.

Comment: Величезне вам спасибі! Дуже допомогли!

Comment: Щодо вжитку прийменника ПО, існує гарна відповідь https://l-ponomar.com/kultura-movy-vzhyvannya-pryjmennyka-po-krok-tretij/
Українською кажуть "вийти на люди".

Comment: @RomanMikhol, «щодо вжитку прийменника ПО» — так, ним не варто зловживати, але це не означає, що його не існує. Є «вибитися/вивести/вийти в люди» і «вийти на люди» — це зовсім різні значення (але, так, в обох випадках «нешкільний» знахідний відмінок).

Comment: @Sasha, "вибитися в люди" - так звучить. Але спробуйте створити речення з іншими формами. У мене виходить лише "вийти до людей" або "вийти (з'явитися) на люди". А "вивести" тільки "в офшор" або "на чисту воду".

Comment: @RomanMikhol, мені особисто здається, що є багато варіантів. І їх згадував СУМ-11. Але, мабуть, Ви маєте рацію, що деякі значно вживаніші за інші.

Comment: Ну, чесно кажучи, російськомовним школярам теж вбивають в голови, що правильно «по приезде», «по окончании», «по завершении» тощо, коли це «по» має значення «після». Але на Росії усе це давно вважається кніжним стілєм, тому…